# React page is not redirecting

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

i am trying to build basic e-cart. My problem is that during sign up , information coming from the server is store in redux store and i also store in localstorage , it also save there , but sign up page is not redirecting to home page , in case of successful sign up.
Here i am applying logic that if user is not null in store than it should be redirected to  home page. It is only working when i manually refresh page , and then all time it works fine. So how to deal with this problem?

Here is my App.js file code

```
 <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/signUp" component={SignUp} />
          <Route path="/home" component={HomePage} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
```

This is ActionCreator for redux

```
  .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
            localStorage.setItem('user' , JSON.stringify(res.user));
            localStorage.setItem('token' , res.token);
            dispatch({type : ActionTypes.SIGN_UP_USER , payload : res.user})
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            dispatch({type : ActionTypes.SIGN_UP_FAILED , payload : err.message})
        });
```

User Reducer :

```
  switch (actions.type) {
        case ActionTypes.SIGN_UP_USER:
            return {
              user: actions.payload, isLoading: false, isError: null
            }
```

signup page

```
  const signupUser = useSelector(state => state.signUpUser);
    const {isLoading , user , isError} = signupUser;
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(user)
        history.push(`/home`);
    } , []);
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(signUpUser(userName , email , password))
    }
```

and configure store file :

```
const user = localStorage.getItem('user') || null;
{console.log(user)}
const intialState = {
    signUpUser : {user}
}
export const configureStore = () =>{
    const store = createStore(
        combineReducers({
            signUpUser : signUpUser
        }), intialState , applyMiddleware(thunk , logger)
    );
    return store;
}
```

I am following https://github.com/basir/node-react-ecommerce this repository , doing almost same as this  but still not working.

Comment: full code  : https://github.com/meetgamdha02/e-commerce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `user` to the dependencies of the useEffect on your signup page list like this:

```js
const signupUser = useSelector(state => state.const {isLoading , user , isError} = signupUser;
    
useEffect(()=>{
    if(user) history.push(`/home`);
}, [user]);

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(signUpUser(userName , email , password))
}
```

the useEffect would basically run the first time (and check if the user exists), and then run again every time the user changes.

If you put an empty array as the dependency list, the useEffect would only run once when the component is mounted.

Comment: so here we are basically saying that if user change than redirect ? right?

Comment: yes! so the useEffect would basically run the first time (and check if the user exists), and then every time the user changes

Comment: here one more problem is that suppose i signup successfully and then if i go to address " /signUp" manually , then it redirects but for a less amount of time(<1 sec) it show signup screen any solution for that?

Comment: You can create a new question describing that and I will happily answer it too! :-)