# Redirect is not working properly in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Here is my link of describing my first problem [React page is not redirecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62990847/react-page-is-not-redirecting) and code.
this code works perfectly fine but problem here is that when i successfully signup and then if i manually do to "/signUp" then for a less amount time(<1 sec)it shows signup screen. This should not be done it should straightly direct me to "/home". Any solution for this?

Comment: Its because you are checking authentication from state or props, store your token from localstorage and make separate routes for authenticated and unauthencated users and add <Redirect to='/' /> in those switches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to conditionally render routes according to whether the user is authenticated.

You will need to connect your redux store to the component that renders the routes and get the `user` from the redux store.

Here is an example:

```js
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'


...
<Switch>
    {user
        ?
        // the user is autenticated
        <>
            <Route path="/home" component={HomePage} />
            <Redirect to="/home" />
        </>
        :
        // the user is not autenticated
        <>
            <Route path="/signUp" component={SignUp} />
            <Redirect to="/signUp" />
        </>
    }
</Switch>
...
```

What this example will do is the following:

1. if the user is authenticated:

   - the user can navigate to the `/home` route
   - if they go to a different route, it will redirect them to `/home`
2. if the user is NOT authenticated:

   - the user can navigate to the `/signUp` route
   - if they go to a different route, it will redirect them to `/signUp`

I am using `<>...</>` which is equivalent to `<React.Fragment>`, which allows you to include adjacent elements in it, which is otherwise not allowed